# Bison and doesn't name a type error

Tags: c++, linker, bison

I have the following files:

**CP.h**

```
#ifndef CP_H_
#define CP_H_

class CP {
public:
        enum Cardinalite {VIDE = '\0', PTINT = '?', AST = '*', PLUS = '+'};

        CP(Cardinalite myCard);
        virtual ~CP();
private:
        Cardinalite card;
};

#endif /* CP_H_ */
```

And **dtd.y**

```
%{

using namespace std;
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "AnalyseurDTD/DtdDocument.h"
#include "AnalyseurDTD/CP.h"

void yyerror(char *msg);
int yywrap(void);
int yylex(void);

DtdDocument * doc = new DtdDocument();
%}

%union { 
        char *s;
        DtdElement * dtdelt;
        CP *cpt;
        CP::Cardinalite card;
}
```

And the following strange error:

```
AnalyseurDTD/dtd.y:20:2: error: ‘CP’ does not name a type
AnalyseurDTD/dtd.y:21:2: error: ‘CP’ does not name a type
```

The stange thing is that if I put CP *cpt; after DtdDocument * doc = new DtdDocument(); I have no error :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the header in your scanner file before you include `*.tab.h`

```
// scanner.l file

%{
#include "myheader.h" 
#include "yacc.tab.h"

// other C/C++ code

%}

// helper definitions

%%

// scanner rules 

%%
```

`%union` is defined in `yacc.tab.h` so when you compile you need to make sure the compiler sees your new type definitions before it process `yacc.tab.h`

Answer (score 3):

Recently I am working with flex and bison. There are several advises that may be helpful for you to locate the problem:

1. Compile the files one by one to make sure there is no obvious compiling error in your code.
2. Check the header file generated by bison (something like `*.tab.h`). Find the definition of  `YYSTYPE`. There is a high probability that it doesn't include your header file `AnalyseurDTD/CP.h`.
3. If it's just the case, you should always include `AnalyseurDTD/CP.h` before you include the `*.tab.h`. Add it wherever needed to make sure the class `CP` is defined before `YYSTYPE`.
4. If you still cannot locate the problem, try use `void *cpt;` in the union, then add type conversion in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the error is from Bison?  I would venture it comes from your compiler.  And probably when it was trying to compile the scanner.  I would suggest that your `YYSTYPE` is not properly defined in your generated header.  Try

```
%code requires { #include "AnalyseurDTD/CP.h" }
```

so that dtd.h is self-contained.  See the documentation about `%code`.

And please, *always* provide logs that are complete enough so that we can try to understand your problem.  Here, you don't even show the tool you ran, and I hardly think it is Bison.

Comment: Thanks but I it fails, it seems to do not find my CP.h : `AnalyseurDTD/dtd.y:17:29: fatal error: AnalyseurDTD/CP.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Well, fix your paths.  Pass appropriate -I to your compiler.  And again, post complete logs if you want actual help instead of divination.